# jQuery - scroll to element with dynamic class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do is the following: When I click an element, it clones all children to another div and scrolls to the clone of the div I clicked.

For that I am adding a class `vp` to the clone of the clicked object. That works fine. Then I added this to scroll to that element:

```
var target = output.find(".vp");

$(".output").animate({
  scrollLeft: target.offset().left
}, 500);
```

But that isn't working. On the first click, it's working, but afterwards it's scrolling to an element that hasn't class `.vp`.

Here's a snippet. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

```js
var output = $(".output div");

$(".wrapper div").click(function(){
  
  var size = $(".wrapper div").length;
  output.css('width', size * 100 + 'vw');
  
  var index = $(this).index() + 1;
  
  output.empty();
  
  $(".wrapper div").each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("vp");
    $(this).clone().appendTo(output);
  });
    
  $(".output div div:nth-child(" + index + ")").addClass("vp");
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    var target = output.find(".vp");
  
    $(".output").animate({
      scrollLeft: target.offset().left
    }, 500);
  }, 10);
  
});
```

```css
body{
  width:100vw;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0;padding:0;
}
.wrapper{
  height:100%;
  width:100vw;
  background:none;
}
.wrapper div{
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  margin:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.output{
  font-size:2em;
  height:200px;
  width:100vw;
  display:block;
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
.output div{
  height:200px;
  width:100vw;
}
.output div div{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:100vw;
  height:200px;
}
.vp{
  background-color:#a0a0a0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>

<div class="output">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your function like this

```
    $(".output").animate({
      scrollLeft: target.width() * (index-1)
    }, 500);
```

```js
var output = $(".output div");

$(".wrapper div").click(function(){
  
  var size = $(".wrapper div").length;
  output.css('width', size * 100 + 'vw');
  
  var index = $(this).index() + 1;
  
  output.empty();
  
  $(".wrapper div").each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("vp");
    $(this).clone().appendTo(output);
  });
    
  $(".output div div:nth-child(" + index + ")").addClass("vp");
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    var target = output.find(".vp");
  
    $(".output").animate({
      scrollLeft: target.width() * (index-1)
    }, 500);
  }, 10);
  
});
```

```css
body{
  width:100vw;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0;padding:0;
}
.wrapper{
  height:100%;
  width:100vw;
  background:none;
}
.wrapper div{
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  margin:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.output{
  font-size:2em;
  height:200px;
  width:100vw;
  display:block;
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
.output div{
  height:200px;
  width:100vw;
}
.output div div{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:100vw;
  height:200px;
}
.vp{
  background-color:#a0a0a0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>

<div class="output">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's working perfectly. Do you know why I can't use `offset().left` ?